# How to implement pagination for Solr results in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, solr, pagination, faceted-search

I have searched and results in place. The returned results are in JSON and I am using the easyPaginate jquery plugin to paginate the results.

Current rows are limit to 100 and 10 results per page. The total result for search term is 15000(e.g.)

Problem - The result is more than 15000 documents for any search term and I want a way to search using facets where at a time only 100 results are loaded and when user reaches the last page of results, the next 100 results are loaded.

My try-
I tried looking for pagination and solr and on this link(https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/pagination-of-results.html), found there is Cursor mark that allows to do something similar to what I want. But I would appreciate if someone could give me examples of what I am trying to do is achievable and if so am i missing something here?

I am fairly new to these concepts and any help is greatly appreciated. I understand question can be too vague but let me know what other things I need to post. I tried to google but really couldn't find something really helpful.

Comment: Do you have an example that clearly explains what you're trying to do? Is the issue on the CI or the Solr side? How are you searching? How are you generating the result page?

Comment: What library are you using to connect to the solr?